# Forcing different size svg images into symmetric grid

Tags: graphics, floats, errors, subfloats, grids

I have a grid of 4 svg images that I am trying to force into a grid. My problem is that when I put them into LaTex the grid alignment is slightly off.

I have tried:

- moving the `\hfill` to different posititons,
- importing the SVG with set parameters and
- using top alignment as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286389/spacing-in-2x2-images?rq=1).

Instead, neither method has worked for me. My output looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includesvg[width=7cm,height=5.1cm]{images/image1a}
    \caption{svg 1}
    \label{fig:image1a}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%  
  \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includesvg[width=7cm,height=5.1cm]{images/image1b}
    \caption{svg 2}
    \label{fig:image1b}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%  
  \begin{subfigure}[hbt]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includesvg[width=7cm,height=5.1cm]{images/image1c}
    \caption{svg 3}
    \label{fig:image1c}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[hbt]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includesvg[width=7cm,height=5.1cm]{images/image1d}
    \caption{svg 4}
    \label{fig:image1d}
  \end{subfigure}
  %\hfill
  \caption{Image1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

***minimum working example***

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,a4paper,afrikaans,english,masters-t,goldenblock]{usthesis}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[afrikaans, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg} % To be able to add SVG images
\usepackage{usbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\setcitestyle{square}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Sets page size and margins %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,  total={210.2mm,297.3mm}, left=25mm, right = 25mm, top=26.3mm, bottom=43.8mm }

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Error here %%%%%%

% Insert the 4 figures here in even grid (error in equal spacing)
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includesvg[width=7cm,height=5.1cm]{images/image1a}
    \caption{svg 1}
    \label{fig:image1a}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%  % <-- \hfill is new
  \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includesvg[width=7cm,height=5.1cm]{images/image1b}
    \caption{svg 2}
    \label{fig:image1b}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%  % <-- \hfill is new
  \begin{subfigure}[hbt]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includesvg[width=7cm,height=5.1cm]{images/image1c}
    \caption{svg 3}
    \label{fig:image1c}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[hbt]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includesvg[width=7cm,height=5.1cm]{images/image1d}
    \caption{svg 4}
    \label{fig:image1d}
  \end{subfigure}
  %\hfill
  \caption{Image1}
\end{figure}

In text reference: Fig.~\ref{fig:image1a}.

\bibliography{sample} % no need for bibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{svg 1}
            \label{fig:image1a}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{svg 2}
            \label{fig:image1b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{svg 3}
            \label{fig:image1c}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{svg 4}
            \label{fig:image1d}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{...}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @User , yes but my images are different sizes so I would like to force them to conform to equal specifications. The demo images you have above are of the same size .